# Exchange 2013 EWS PHP - FindItem Restriction Recipient

Tags: php, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, restriction

Is there a way to search for the recipient in EWS?
I use this restriction for searching for the sender:

```
<IsEqualTo>
    <FieldURI FieldURI="message:From" />
    <FieldURIOrConstant>
        <Constant Value="(searchEmailAddress)" />
    </FieldURIOrConstant>
</IsEqualTo>
<IsEqualTo>
    <FieldURI FieldURI="message:Sender" />
    <FieldURIOrConstant>
        <Constant Value="(searchEmailAddress)" />
    </FieldURIOrConstant>
</IsEqualTo>
```

But I can't find a way to search for the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayTo is the only recipient property returned by the FindItem operation. So, to search on DisplayTo, do this:

```
  <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
    <m:ItemShape>
      <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
    </m:ItemShape>
    <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="1" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
    <m:Restriction>
      <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DisplayTo" />
        <t:Constant Value="Somebody" />
      </t:Contains>
    </m:Restriction>
    <m:ParentFolderIds>
      <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />
    </m:ParentFolderIds>
  </m:FindItem>
```